# getting only last class assigned with this.class

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype-oriented

Please can anyone see what is wrong in this code, 
I have 2 class images with .man and .girl which contains 10 images in each.
next I have 2 div's #manCount and #girlCount which display total images number (10 in each)

when I move one image to #drop, It decrease 1 number from #manCount. So ther are total 10 images with class name .man, When the last image is moved to #drop I get a pop up that all images are processed.

now I also wants to process .girl class images but when i have both classess initialize it only work with .girl class.

```
function Dragger(c){
this.classname = c;

}
Dragger.prototype.Init = function(){
    var classM = this.classname;
    var manCount = parseInt($("#"+classM+"Count").text());
    $("."+classM).draggable();
        $("#drop").droppable({
          drop: function() {
           if(manCount <= 0){
               alert("There are no more pictures left. " + classM );
               return false;
           }
            manCount -= 1;
           $("#"+classM+"Count").text(manCount);
              }
        });
};

var man = new Dragger("man");
man.Init();
```

above code runs just fine but when I initilize a new object

```
    var man = new Dragger("man");
    man.Init();
    var girl = new Dragger("girl");
    girl.Init();
```

It always pick girl object, any help where I am doing wrong?

It always return me female object on drag. 
A screenshot of display: http://screensnapr.com/v/SrsyGz.png

Here is problem: http://screensnapr.com/v/hxrZYa.png

Thanks

Edit:

Ok i have fixed this issue by adding mouseover event, i am not sure how perfect it is thogh as i am pretty new to it but it works as expected

```
$(".man").mouseover(function(){
  var man = new Dragger("man");
  man.Init();
});
$(".girl").mouseover(function(){
  var girl = new Dragger("girl");
  girl.Init();
});
```

Comment: Please capitalize `I` and letters at the beginning of sentences to increase readability.

Comment: Sorry fixed some, will take care next.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it’s because you are calling `$('#drop').droppable()` in the `Init` function, so it gets initiated more than once on the same element (#drop).

Comment: thanks for input, i am not sure what is happening as i am prettry new to jquery, i think issue is i initilzes both classes same time so it picked only last one, so it always descrease that last object value. here a screen what is happening http://screensnapr.com/v/hxrZYa.png

Comment: you should probably put the logic in the drop callback instead to avoid scoping problems.

Comment: Thank i will check, i just actually found a solution, only initialize object when mouseover, can you please see above and tell me if it is fine, i am pretty new to this concept. Thanks again.